# How to order columns in RStudio according to real column order in data.fame?

Tags: r, sorting

I would like to remove some specific columns from my `data.frame`. I need to visually inspect data in the columns. The column names are often complicated, so I would like to remove them by column number, for example: `df <- df[ -c(3, 7, 103, 105, 112, 114, 150, 333) ]`.

I use R to identify the column numbers, but they are not the same as in the real `data.frame`.

Is there a way to sort the column order in R, so that all column numbers line up? Thank you.

**Screenshot of column error:**

[image]

```
 names(df)[ 51 ]
 [1] "B4GALT4"
```

Comment: Can you show a small example.  is there any pattern in column names if they are different?  also, as mentioned in the post, if the numbers are not the same, how do you want to get the index,  If the column names are mixed.  an option is to order with `gtools::mixedorder(colnames(df))`

Comment: Yes, I understand. Thank you for your comment. I am trying to generate an example, but it is difficult. On my real data I have this problem. Using a simple example, I so far do not have the problem. Still trying to create an example...

Comment: Can you show the `names(df)[c(3, 7, 103, 105, 112, 114, 150, 333) ]`

Comment: Yes, on my real data, it shows these names: ```[1] "ACP7"     "AGMO"     "CDH5"     "CEBPG"    "CENPF"    "CENPI"    "COQ10B"   "KCNQ1OT1"```. The first two are correct, but then not anymore. Not sure if this info is helpful, though? Still trying to create an example. Thank you.

Comment: @akrun - Pfffff, trying to join dfs, move columns around and sort them by name, but no luck reproducing so far :(

Comment: @akrun - Sorry, no luck reproducing, but there may be a smarter way to solve my problem. This is now an entirely different question, but do you know how to remove any column in which at least 6 values are either NA or 0?

Comment: @akrun - Maybe I'll search through SO for that answer. Thank you for your help today. You are always so on top of things!   :)

Comment: I think the main question to ask here is why the column numbers are not the same as in the real data.frame? What do you do in previous steps which makes them inconsistent.

Comment: I am mainly using the following functions: ```as_tibble```, ```rownames_to_column``` (dplyr), ```as.data.frame```, ```lapply``` (log transformation on data.frame). I also just noticed something else. When in the top-left data table pane in R Studio, I click the ```>``` symbol to view columns 51-100, when I mouse-over the columns that I see, it says that these are 101-150, which is strange. That probably relates to the problem.

Comment: @RonakShah - The column names that I want to refer to according to R Studio are: ```names(df)[c(3, 7, 103, 105, 112, 114, 150, 333) ]```, but I get the correct column names by using ```names(df)[c(3, 7, 203, 205, 212, 214, 250, 633) ]```, so there is something off, I think when going beyond column 50. I am very sorry for not being able to pinpoint and create an example :(  Thank you for your help, though.

Comment: How do you know that column number according to RStudio are - `c(3, 7, 103, 105, 112, 114, 150, 333)` ? Can you show the screenshot? It is possible that there is a bug in R-Studio for displaying columns more than some `x` number.

Comment: See screenshot above. When mousing over column 51, it says "column 101". The code below the screenshot shows that this is column 51.

Comment: What is your Rstudio version?

Comment: Version 1.2.5042 (on a Mac).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in earlier version of R-Studio which has been fixed now. See https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/4682

So if you update your R-Studio to latest version you should see the correct column numbers in `View`.

Comment: Woohooo! Awesome. I am going to do that. Thank you so much for your patience with me!